# Communication between two gnome-terminal sessions

Tags: python, subprocess, gnome-terminal

I have python program main.py

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
  "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x 'handler.py'", 
  shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('Text sent to handler for display\n')
```

where handler.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "In handler..."
```

Program main.py opens a new gnome-terminal and runs handler.py to display "In handler...". How can I get handler.py to receive and print "Text sent to the handler for display" sent from main.py?

The answer provided to question "[Sending strings between python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396628/sending-strings-between-to-python-scripts-using-subprocess-pipes)" is the idea of what I'm after, where handler.py runs in the terminal session created by main.py.

Comment: you mean a server? lookup IPC.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit to the OP regarding a similar answered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your handler to read from a file given at the command line instead of `stdin`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import sys
import time

print "In handler..."
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(5)
```

Then you could create a named pipe in `main.py`, to send the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from subprocess import Popen

fifo = "fifo"
os.mkfifo(fifo)
p = Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-x", "python", "handler.py", fifo])
with open(fifo, 'wb') as file:
    file.write("Text sent to handler for display")
os.remove(fifo)
p.wait()
```

Comment: Didn't know about mkfifo - this is exactly what I was after.